Cloudflare resolves but Google doesn't. Why?
I am in Mexico.
This fails:
% curl -s -H 'accept: application/dns-json' 'https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=www.bispebjerghospital.dk&type=A' | jq .
{
  "Status": 2,
  "TC": false,
  "RD": true,
  "RA": true,
  "AD": false,
  "CD": false,
  "Question": [
    {
      "name": "www.bispebjerghospital.dk",
      "type": 1
    }
  ],
  "Comment": [
    "EDE(22): No Reachable Authority (time limit exceeded)"
  ]
}

but this succeeds:
dig @8.8.8.8 www.bispebjerghospital.dk

Why? What requirements does Cloudflare require of a domain to resolve its record?
The map shown at whatsmydns shows red X's for some locations.
EDIT: Marcus in the comments seems to have no issue with the Cloudflare. So since I suspect this is an anycast issue, here are the IP addresses I see for Cloudflare:
% nslookup cloudflare-dns.com
Server:     10.2.9.68
Address:    10.2.9.68#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   cloudflare-dns.com
Address: 104.16.249.249
Name:   cloudflare-dns.com
Address: 104.16.248.249
Name:   cloudflare-dns.com
Address: 2606:4700::6810:f9f9
Name:   cloudflare-dns.com
Address: 2606:4700::6810:f8f9

EDIT2: NS records as requested:
% dig www.bispebjerghospital.dk NS 
;; communications error to 10.2.9.68#53: timed out

; <<>> DiG 9.18.24-1-Debian <<>> www.bispebjerghospital.dk NS
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 61936
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.bispebjerghospital.dk. IN  NS

;; Query time: 15 msec
;; SERVER: 10.2.9.68#53(10.2.9.68) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 02 13:00:23 CST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54

% dig @8.8.8.8 www.bispebjerghospital.dk NS 

; <<>> DiG 9.18.24-1-Debian <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.bispebjerghospital.dk NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40469
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.bispebjerghospital.dk. IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
bispebjerghospital.dk.  900 IN  SOA ns3.regionh.dk. webmasteradmin.regionh.dk. 2008030648 10800 3600 2592000 900

;; Query time: 256 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 02 12:58:38 CST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117

% dig +short cloudflare-dns.com NS
ns1.cloudflare-dns.com.
ns2.cloudflare-dns.com.
ns3.cloudflare-dns.com.

EDIT3: NextDNS succeeds:
% curl -s -H 'accept: application/dns-json' 'https://dns.nextdns.io/dns-query?name=www.bispebjerghospital.dk&type=A' | jq .
{
  "Status": 0,
  "TC": false,
  "RD": true,
  "RA": true,
  "AD": false,
  "CD": false,
  "Question": [
    {
      "name": "www.bispebjerghospital.dk.",
      "type": 1
    }
  ],
  "Answer": [
    {
      "name": "www.bispebjerghospital.dk.",
      "type": 1,
      "TTL": 3600,
      "data": "128.0.75.219"
    }
  ]
}

EDIT4: I can't query from ns3.region.dk directly:
% dig @ns3.regionh.dk www.bispebjerghospital.dk
;; communications error to 128.0.75.226#53: timed out

EDIT5: Seems like that previous command should have worked, since it works on dnsexit.com:


no, that doesn't fail for me; the Answer section's first element's data attribute contains your A record.; curl -H 'accept: application/dns-json' 'https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=www.bispebjerghospital.dk&type=A' | jq '.Answer[0].data' yields "128.0.75.219". (Note that DNS-over-HTTPS is what I'd consider insanely inefficient, and contributing to a dangerous centralization of a redudandent distributed system, but my dislike for DoH isn't subject of your question.)

@MarcusMüller Cloudflare probably has multiple servers (anycast). If you can, try executing the request from a different continent. The map at whatsmydns offers some suggestions.

Hm, could you help us out by actually including your full JSON reply in the question? That would definitely help diagnose the problem that I can't reproduce locally :) (and, assuming .dk is indicative of the country you're in, we should be on the same continent!)

@MarcusMüller I have added the requested details to the question. I am in Mexico myself, not Denmark.

interesting, what does asking for the NS record yield? I get ns3.regionh.dk. and that resolver actually correctly answers my requests,so this would just seem to be a fault on cloudflare's end.

(my cloudflare dns server indeed is 104.16.248.249)

Regarding "this would just seem to be a fault on cloudflare's end", that would assume that whatsmydns uses DoH/Cloudflare somehow too... I wish I knew if a better way to run DNS queries from multiple locations than whatsmydns...

@MarcusMüller does this work for you? dig @ns3.regionh.dk www.bispebjerghospital.dk If it does, that indicates that it isn't a Cloudflare problem. Since it doesn't work for me.

as said, works flawlessly. But you are pretty certain you're getting the DoH reply from cloudflare, since, well, that's the point about DoH, can't be man-in-the-middled. That it also does not work for you might have something to do with local traffic rules, maybe? or maybe there's really a BGP / routing problem on AS level? That'd be a bit scary.

Well, if the nameserver as we checked is up and running, and multiple alternative resolvers succeed, then I'm afraid there's likely something wrong on cloudflare's end, not yours.

"EDE(22): No Reachable Authority (time limit exceeded)"


might indicate there's no route between cloudflare's AS and the AS of the authorative nameserver, but that seems unlikely.

I wish I knew if a better way to run DNS queries from multiple locations than whatsmydns...

As wasteful as that sounds, spin up a (free tier) AWS EC2 instance (a VM) in different regions.
